# how to get a li tag to overflow

Tags: css, list, html-lists

I am trying to use the LI (inside an UL tag) tag instead of the TD (inside a table) but keep hitting upon a problem, that is when I reached the certain width of the #wrapper id in css, it keeps stacking the next image below, which is not what I want to do.

I want to create a film strip where thumbnails are displayed

I want to replace the table where the images are being displayed for a much more responsive CSS in the future

I can't seem to post the CSS styling to show you what I mean because the editor is driving me insane

Comment: Add the respective code.  So that we can help you.

Comment: Like I said, the editor on this site is driving me insane, I can't somehow format it properly

Comment: 1) paste your css in the editor 2) select the css which you pasted 3) click the curly braces button of the editor toolbar and then the editor will format your css - then we can help you –

Comment: so create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net and post a link to it in the editor

Comment: ok, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/riddleme/LURyg/

Comment: Oh my gosh, some of these sites really need to sort their editors out, here is the new link http://jsfiddle.net/riddleme/LURyg/2/